# Railsでwhereとorderとselectを使って配列が取得できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

表題の通り以下のコードを書いて配列を取得したいのですが、上手くいきません。

```
video_ids = Youtube.where(channel_id:channel_id).order("youtube_created desc").select("video_id").limit(5)
```

上のコードを使って、Youtubeモデルのvideo_idカラムが５つ取得できるようにしたいのですが、どこが間違っているのでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/122209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決できました。

selectを使ってカラム名を取得できると勘違いしていたのが問題で、代わりにpluckやmapを使うことが解決できました。

```
video_ids = Youtube.where(channel_id:channel_id).order(youtube_created: :desc).first(5).pluck(:video_id)
```

また、当質問は「マルチポスト」とのご指摘を受けましたが、マルチポストがマナー違反だと言うのは知りませんでした。

以後は、正しく質問サイトを利用できるように注意していきます。

Comment: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=マルチポスト 多分、stackoverflowでは明示的にマルチポストを禁止しているわけでは無かったと思います。それよりもマルチポストされることで放置される質問が出てくる可能性があることが問題かと。。。どこかで解決しちゃったら解決しなかったサイトの質問に得られた回答を書く人って居ないですよね？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
マルチポスト自体は問題ではなく、解決策が分かった質問を放置するのが問題なのですね。
ご指摘ありがとうございました。